# GCP Cloud Run - Retrieve all revisions not serving traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've been trying in vain to get all cloud run revisions not serving traffic so I can prune them. The docs don't seem to provide much help. Here's what I have:

```
 gcloud run revisions list 
  --region <region> 
  --service <service> 
  --filter="status.conditions.type['Active'].status:'True'" 
  --sort-by="~metadata.creationTimestamp"
```

I haven't seen anything the yaml that indicates a revision is currently serving traffic that I can filter on in the cloud console except in the ui. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try:

```
gcloud run revisions list \
   --filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" \
   --format='value(metadata.name)'
```

Then specify the `region`

Or:

```
gcloud run revisions list \    
--region <region> \    
--service <service name> \    
--filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" \    
--format='value(metadata.name)'
```